# Nginx not logging after Logrotate

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, logging, cron, logrotate

I've a nginx reverse proxy with custom log files (depending on hostname)

pwd : `/var/log/nginx/domain/fqdn.(log|err)`

Since some time (maybe after switching to Ubuntu 23.10), my log files are very often empty.

Here is the logrotate config

```
root@rev-proxy:~# cat /etc/logrotate.d/nginx 
/var/log/nginx/*/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 14
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 www-data adm
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi \
    endscript
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
    endscript
}
```

After logrotate run, nginx can't log anymore to the differents log files until i reload / restart / force logrotate.

I've tried to replace `invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1` with `invoke-rc.d nginx reload >/dev/null 2>&1` but not working.

Last logs of last file are always between 00:00 and 00:15. So i think this is when logrotate is rotating the logs.

All log files have `www-data:adm` owner with **644** mask.

Does someone have an idea ?

Thank's

Comment: What happens if you run `invoke-rc.d nginx rotate` on the command line?

Comment: logs work after manually reopening

Answer (score 0):

Check that /var/log has execute permissions for "other" users.

Try replacing the postrotate.d command with

```
service nginx reload >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Yeah, mask is 775

Comment: and already tried reload command, without success